# Avoiding FormatException with Convert.ToDouble('Infinity') on Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows, windows-10

How do I parse "Infinity" on Windows 10? I ran into this when using RowFilter:
e.g.

```
rowFilter = "[ColumnName] = 'Infinity'"
```

This code works on Windows 7/8 but breaks on Windows 10 with a FormatException.

Answer (score 1):

The infinity symbol is culture-specific. It appears the symbol used by the default (us-en) culture changed between Windows 8 and 10. I don't know how or even if it's possible to specify the `InvariantCulture` for `RowFilter` expressions: it seems to assume `CurrentCulture`. The `RowFilter` expression above will work with `PositiveInfinitySymbol` of `CurrentCulture`:

```
rowFilter = String.Format("[ColumnName] = '{0}'", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol)
```