# Input string was not in a correct format on Convert.ToDouble("Infinity")

Tags: c#, type-conversion, formatexception

Why would the following fail with a System.FormatException on 64-bit Windows 10, but runs fine on 32-bit Windows 7?  Both machines have .NET Framework 4.6.1 installed.

```
Convert.ToDouble("Infinity");
```

I have searched and cannot find an answer to this.

Comment: [Probably related...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112978/avoiding-formatexception-with-convert-todoubleinfinity-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string used for Infinity is culture specific and may have even had different values between Win 7 & 10 (can't confirm that at the moment).

Try using the constant instead of hard coding a string:

```
Convert.ToDouble(NumberFormatInfo.PositiveInfinitySymbol);
```